# How to add assets images in carousel_slider?

Tags: flutter, image, assets, image-slider

i am tring to add images in carousel flutter and i make a list of images from my assets but i am facing this error.

> ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///home/zr/untitled%20folder/snap/flutter/PROJECTS/nic/nic/assets/images/ataltunel.jpg)

note: (i dont't want to load images from network) please give some ideas to solve it.

this is the code....!!!!!

```dart
body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CarouselSlider(
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                      height: 170.0, autoPlay: true, enlargeCenterPage: true),
                  items: _slideimages.map((i) {
                    return Builder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: Image.network(i),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont't want to load images from network, then try loading the images from local assets, for which create a folder /assests and include that in your pubspec.yml file and run pub get command and once done add those images in _slideimages list and use it.
use Image.assert(i)

Answer (score 0):

if you using images from asset then use Image.asset("path");
or you using image file then you can use Image.file("file path");

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Image.asset` to load from assets.

```dart
child: Image.network(i), /// make sure to provide current path.
```

Make sure to add on pubspec.yaml  file.
Find more about [assets-and-images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)
.

Comment: Thanks God I find You bro, I need help bro.
I stuck on this issue, Kindly help me on this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75831070/flutter-how-to-swipe-button-on-both-direction]